# How to change field on HTML file when button is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I change the HTML itself when I press a button? When I press a button in this case, the value is stored as "displayCount". Is there a way in which I can directly see the count on the HTML code? If it was press one time, I could see the number 1 on the HTML itself, not as a variable?

Thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title> </title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="button" value="Count" id="countButton" />

        <p>The button was pressed <span id="displayCount">0</span> times.</p>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var count = 0;
            var button = document.getElementById("countButton");
            var display = document.getElementById("displayCount");

            button.onclick = function() {
                count++;
                display.innerHTML = count;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

For example, if button was pressed once, one of the line would change from

```
   <p>The button was pressed <span id="displayCount">1</span> times.</p>
```

Comment: It will show number on html see [demo](http://jsbin.com/voyudenu/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/j7cTu/) Fiddle works as you want..

i changed your script into :

```
 var count = 0;

function countIt(){

  var button = document.getElementById("countButton");
  var display = document.getElementById("displayCount");
    count++;
    display.innerHTML = count;
  }
```

and your HTML to :

```
  <input type="button" onclick="countIt()" value="Count" id="countButton" />

<p>The button was pressed <span id="displayCount">0</span> times.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

hope this will help you

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var clicks = 0;
function onClick() {
    clicks += 1;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
};
</script>
<button type="button" onClick="onClick()">Count</button>
<p>The button was pressed : <a id="clicks">0</a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/edisonator/CHWEy/1/) is my jsfiddle to your problem.

I delete the varible `count` you used, and just use the number on your HTML, it works well.

```
var button = document.getElementById("countButton");
var display = document.getElementById("displayCount");

button.onclick = function(){
    display.innerHTML = ++display.innerHTML;
}
```

Thanks,

Edison

Answer (score 0):

I guess you might want to use `parseInt()` explicitly increment the `count` as an integer  like this:

```
var count = parseInt(display.textContent,10);
```

Your code could go like this:

```
var button = document.getElementById("countButton");
var display = document.getElementById("displayCount");
var count = parseInt(display.textContent,10);
button.onclick = function(){
    count++;
    display.innerHTML = count;
}
```

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/naokiota/9dQjv/2/

The document of the `parseInt()` is here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script>

    var count = 0;
    function counts()
    {
    var result = document.getElementById('txtbxid');
    count ++ ;
    result.value = count;
    }
    </script>
     <input type="text"  id="txtbxid" name="txtbxid">

    <input type="button"  id="add" name="add" value="add" onClick="counts()">
```